# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219 general error

Tags: php, laravel

There are a lot of people having this issue and there are some solutions but i just couldn't resolve mine.Codes are down there. when i go localhost:8000/article i get my articles. There is no problem. I can go **/article/create**. But when **submit** i get  MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219 error. when i go **article/2** i get MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219 error.

ArticleController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Article;
//use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $articles = Article::all();
        return view('articles.index',compact('articles'));
    }
    public function show($id){
        $article = Article::findOrFail($id);
        return view('articles.show',compact('article'));
    }

    public function create(){
        return view('articles.create');
    }

    public function store(){
        $input = Request::all();
        return $input;
    }
}
```

create.blade.php

```
@extends('app')


@section('content')
    <h1>Write a New Article</h1>

    <br/>

        {!! Form::open(['url' => 'article']) !!}
        <div class="form-group">
            {!!Form::label('title','Title:')!!}
            {!! Form::text('title',null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('body','Body:') !!}
            {!! Form::textarea('body',null,['class' => 'form-control'])!!}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {!!Form::submit('Add Article',['class'=> 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
        </div>
        {!! Form::close() !!}

@stop
```

index.blade.php

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')
    <h1>Articles</h1>
    <br/>
    <?php foreach ($articles as $article): ?>
        <article>
            <h2>
                <a href="/article/{{$article->id}}">{{$article->title}}</a>
            </h2>
            <div class="body">{{$article->body}}</div>
        </article>
    <?php endforeach ?>
@stop
```

routes.php

```
<?php

Route::get('about','PagesController@about');
Route::get('contact','PagesController@contact');

Route::get('article','ArticleController@index');
Route::get('article/create','ArticleController@create');
Route::get('article/{id}','ArticleController@show');

Route::post('article','ArticleController@store');
```

**EDIT 1**
`php artisan route:list` output here:

```
GET|HEAD | about | App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@about    
GET|HEAD | article | App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController@index  
GET|HEAD | article/create | App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController@create 
GET|HEAD | contact | App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@contact
```

**EDIT 2 and SOLUTION**

with `php artisan route:clear` clear your route list and do `php artisan route:list` you will get your all routes. it worked fine for me.

Comment: You are requesting to a route that is not supporting post requests. Laravel makes you to specify your request method in routes. And will not let you request post in pages that need get request. And will throw a MethodNotFound exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change this in `create.blade.php`:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'article']) !!}
```

to this:

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'article.store')) !!}
```

**UPDATE**

Run `php artisan route:clear` to clear routes cache.

Comment: Not working i don't think it's because of that. I don't remember but i think this began after using form facade
Route [article.store] not defined. (View: C:\Users\oguna\Desktop\Laravel Projects\project\resources\views\articles\create.blade.php)

Comment: You said your form is working and you get an error when you submit form. Run `php artisan route:list` and post all info for `articles.store` route please.

Comment: So, there is no `article.store` route in the list. Are you sure you've copy-pasted your `routes.php` and haven't changed anything?

Comment: It's very strange, because I've just tried your routes and I can see `articles.store` route created in the route list. Try also to run `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: Now i have article/{id}

Comment: Sir thank you so much. article.store and article/{id} is now working everything is fine.